# How to use custom glibc to compile VLC 1.1.12

Tags: compilation, vlc, glibc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host)

My problem is as follows:

I need to compile VLC 1.1.12 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.5 (This is the same for development / production environment).

With current version of glibc, VLC throws the following error in 'configure':

```
checking for buggy GNU/libc versions... found
configure: error: Buggy GNU/libc (version 2.5 - 2.7) present. VLC would crash; there is no viable
work-around for this. Check with your distribution vendor on how to update the glibc run-time. Alternatively, build with --disable-nls --disable-mozilla and be sure to not use LibVLC from other applications/wrappers.
```

So I tried to compile glibc 2.9 separately on the server and installed it in a custom location /opt/glibc-2.9

Now I can't figure out if I can use this custom glibc when I try to compile VLC.

Can someone please advice if this is possible and if yes, how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone please advice if this is possible and if yes, how to do this?

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) answer.